# Creating CGridView based on a collection from a mongo db - YII

Tags: mongodb, yii, cgridview

I am trying to create CGridView based on a collection from MongoDB , Can anybody provide me any idea to proceed this ?

I have created the Model class for the collections

```
  <?php
class ContactCollection extends EMongoDocument
    {
   //   public $login;
      public $name;
     // public $pass;

      // This has to be defined in every model, this is same as with standard Yii ActiveRecord
      public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
      {
        return parent::model($className);
      }

      // This method is required!
      public function getCollectionName()
      {
        return 'cartoons';
      }

      public function rules()
      {
        return array(
      //    array('login, pass', 'required'),
     //     array('login, pass', 'length', 'max' => 20),
          array('name', 'length', 'max' => 255),
        );
      }

      public function attributeLabels()
      {
        return array(
       //   'login'  => 'User Login',
          'name'   => 'Full name',
      //    'pass'   => 'Password',
        );
      }
    }
```

My View Class,

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id' =>'BCImported-grid',
    'dataProvider' => ContactCollection::model()->search(),
    'columns' => array('name'),
        )); ?>
```

Now am getting CGridView with null values , I have 50 records in MongoDB , all 50 rows showing in CgridView with empty name value. Can anybody say what mistake am doing ?

Comment: Please share with us what you have done so far.

Comment: What MongoDB extension are you using?

Comment: YiiMongoDbSuite extension

Answer (score 0):

If you can fetch the records you want from MongoDb in the form of an array, then you would be able to make use of Yii's `CArrayDataProvider` class that you can then use with `CGridView`

Hope that helps